# How to concatenate only non-redundant rows in dataframe based on specific features?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, outer-join

I have a very tricky problem and need to perform a concatenate of 1 and 2. The output shall look like `Out`.

```
1:
A B C | Y
1 1 5   1 <---- keep
2 2 5   1 <---- keep

2:
A B C | Y
1 1 6   0 <---- drop, because duplicated on subset=[A,B] with row of table 1.
1 2 6   0 <---- keep
3 3 6   0 <---- keep, despite duplicated on subset=[A,B] within this table.
3 3 7   0 <---- keep, despite duplicated on subset=[A,B] within this table.

Out:
A B C | Y
1 1 5   1
1 2 6   0
2 2 5   1
3 3 6   0
3 3 7   0
```

So, as you can see I can not just drop duplicates based on `subset=[A,B]` after concatenating. This would also drop the rows `3 3 6 0` and `3 3 7 0`.

To Sum up: I just want to concatenate 1 and 2. And if there is a row in table 2 with the same values of A AND B as in table 1, I would like to keep only the rows of table 1. I don't want to drop other duplicates based on A and B within table 2.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar solution as Sandipan, instead I use inner join to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 5, 1], [2, 2, 5, 1]], columns = ['A','B','C', 'Y'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 6, 0], [1, 2, 6, 0], [3, 3, 6, 0], [3, 3, 7, 0]], columns = ['A','B','C', 'Y'])

# Add an index for df2
df2['idx'] = range(len(df2))

# Find the index of common rows by inner join
common_row = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A','B'], how='inner').idx.tolist()

# Remove common rows in df2
df2 = df2[~df2.idx.isin(common_row)]
df2 = df2.iloc[:,0:-1]

# Concat df1 and df2
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df.sort_values(by=['A','B'], ascending=[True, True])
df
```

Comment: This method is more feasible than the first one because in the actual data set column C is not one column but 650 other columns. So thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following using `full outer join` should work (you may want to recorder the rows in the output table if needed):

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 5, 1], [2, 2, 5, 1]], columns = ['A','B','C', 'Y'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 6, 0], [1, 2, 6, 0], [3, 3, 6, 0], [3, 3, 7, 0]], columns = ['A','B','C', 'Y'])
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A','B'], how='outer')
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.C_x if not np.isnan(row.C_x) else row.C_y, axis=1).astype(int)
df['Y'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.Y_x if not np.isnan(row.C_x) else row.Y_y, axis=1).astype(int)
df = df[['A','B','C','Y']]
df.head()

#   A  B  C  Y
#0  1  1  5  1
#1  2  2  5  1
#2  1  2  6  0
#3  3  3  6  0
#4  3  3  7  0
```

Comment: Thank for your support, but in the actual data set col C is not one but 650 cols. This makes that solution a bit infeasible.